# How do I write a script to modify the password expiration values for users on a Windows Server?

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to create several users on Windows 2008 servers and modify the password expiration value to "*Never*". These will be local (not AD) users. I can create them using "*net user*", it's modifying the pass expiry that is killing me. If I do a "*net user username*" it lists the field and its value, but there is no switch (at least not one that the help file references) to modify it, and most of the solutions I saw online suggested installing 3rd party tools, however this solution must be native to Windows (ideally using Powershell). Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I said if I figured out how to do this in Powershell I would post it here, and I am a man of my word.

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "name = 'steve'"  | Set-WmiInstance -Argument @{PasswordExpires = 0}`

This is a boolean value so if you wanted to set a password to expire just change 0 to 1. This is beautiful to me in its simplicity, and I have tested this method updating other WMI objects and it works every time.

Comment: Do you need a script to do this, or do you just need to do this once?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, and considering you want to do it with a script, would be nonsensical to migrate to Super User. I modified the title a little to help make your question clearer. +1 from me.

Answer (score 6):

The simple solution is to create a batch file that issues the following command:

```
net accounts /maxpwage:unlimited
```

However, that will set the maximum password age for *all* accounts on the local machine to unlimited, not just the new accounts that you have created.

If you need a finer level of control (i.e., the ability to set the password expiration values for individual users), you'll need something a little more complicated. The Scripting Guys [share an example](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/10dae29d-5d1d-44d8-9462-4d61f5bb856c) of a VBScript that will modify a local user account so that its password never expires:

```
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000 

strDomainOrWorkgroup = "Fabrikam" 
strComputer = "atl-win2k-01" 
strUser = "KenMeyer" 

Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomainOrWorkgroup & "/" & _ 
    strComputer & "/" & strUser & ",User") 

objUserFlags = objUser.Get("UserFlags") 
objPasswordExpirationFlag = objUserFlags OR ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD 
objUser.Put "userFlags", objPasswordExpirationFlag  
objUser.SetInfo
```

It would be easy to modify this to work for any user of your choice, or even to create a new user.

Finally, [here's an example in C#](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/c-net-setting-or-clearing-the-password-never-expires-flag-for-a-user/), which you should be able to port to PowerShell. I'm not much of a PS expert, but considering it uses the .NET Framework, the above code should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thx, I will look at these solutions. This is for a script, I am trying to completely automate application server setup for a webfarm, and there are a few pieces that I haven't been able to figure out how to easily script (like this one)...If I figure out how to convert the C# to powershell I will post that here as well (these scripts are all written in powershell). Thx again, FYI I love the Scripting Guys...

Answer (score 1):

From [this technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/cb1e2b10-b75f-4916-a0b1-14bb0bc94988).

```
$computer = $env:Computername
$account = ([adsi]"WinNT://$computer/TestAccount")
$account.PasswordExpired = 1
$account.psbase.commitchanges()
```

You can add the domain before the computer name if you need to.

Comment: Nice.  I don't use WMI all that much, so I didn't think to look there.

Comment: Forgot to mention...your script above set the actual expired flag, not the willexpire flag. But thx for the help anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Set **password never expires** for local user. Do not change other flags:

```
$ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000

$username = 'user'
$user = [adsi] "WinNT://./$username"
$user.UserFlags = $user.UserFlags[0] -bor $ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
$user.SetInfo()
```

[ADS_USER_FLAG_ENUM enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772300(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

works for me:

`WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='ftpuser'" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE`

*replace **ftpuser** with correct user name*

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions weren't working for me so I tweaked Jason's solution to:

```
$svrname = $env:computername
$user = ([adsi]"WinNT://$svrname/Administrator")
$user.userflags = 66049
$user.psbase.commitchanges()
```

The userflags value determines what tickboxes are checked for the user - this one is a basic "password doesn't expire" value. Can't seem to work out how it the numbers go together, the below may be useful but according to that I've got a reserved value enabled which doesn't make sense.

http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm

Instead I just enabled the options I needed on a test box and retrieved the value. Is the most reliable means of determining what you need I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I took Deadly-Bagel's solution and it didn't work, until I made a small change.  See below:

```
$svrname = $env:computername
$user = ([adsi]"WinNT://$svrname/Administrator")
$user.psbase.InvokeSet("userflags", 66049)
$user.psbase.commitchanges()
```